# Wordpress - Most of my posts titled as "auto draft" and i can't change it

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I'm developing a magazine/blog site with wordpress for my school project. After selecting theme and all that stuff, I started to add my content into site via posts section in wordpress. After writing some articles i noticed that my titles are all "Auto Draft". After many tries, i managed to fix it for some of my articles but others remain same. I've fixed it even with JQuery in add post section but it only fixes when I'm viewing that post. When I look at my posts in home page article's title is same:"Auto Draft". Can you help me fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just my inexperience. You must make your theme default and disable all plugins if you're having same problem with me. Then activate all plugins and your theme one by one and check your site each time. You can easily find the source of the problem then.